# TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'Binary' when using boto3 and DynamoDB

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I am storing user credentials in a dynamoDB table using python and boto3. Hashed passwords and their salt are bytes type. DynamoDB apparently [supports `bytes` type](https://https:/https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-dynamodb-support-for-binary-data/) but it isn't clear how well this works with [boto3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/_modules/boto3/dynamodb/types.html). When attempting to pass a password hash retrieved from DynamoDB into the `hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac()` function this throws the following error:
`TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'Binary'`

Looking at how the `bytes` type was stored in DynamoDB it is easy to see why:
`Binary(b'\x91\xd1>F\xfa\x05\xa1\x8a\xbd\x01\xfft\x04&`)

I am familiar with binary strings, but have not seen them wrapped with `Binary()` before. Can anyone explain a way to recover just the binary string?

I notice that the boto3 docs linked above specify the following methods for `Binary` type:

```
class Binary:
    """A class for representing Binary in dynamodb

    Especially for Python 2, use this class to explicitly specify
    binary data for item in DynamoDB. It is essentially a wrapper around
    binary. Unicode and Python 3 string types are not allowed.
    """

    def __init__(self, value):
        if not isinstance(value, BINARY_TYPES):
            types = ', '.join([str(t) for t in BINARY_TYPES])
            raise TypeError(f'Value must be of the following types: {types}')
        self.value = value

    ... 

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Binary({self.value!r})'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.value

    def __bytes__(self):
        return self.value
```

The `__repr__` method is clearly being called on my `bytes` type, is there some way to avoid this or to use another method to recover just the `bytes`?

My function call appears as follows:

```
async def authenticate(email: str = Form(...), password: str = Form(...)):
    response = table.get_item(Key={'email': email})
    item = response['Item']
    stored_salt = item['salt']
    stored_password = item['password']
    ...
```

Comment: It has a `__bytes__` operator, so you can just cast it to bytes with `bytes(item['salt'])`, or do I misunderstand your question?

Comment: @AnonCoward 's comment solved it for me